# Xib doesn't load as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

It has been a while since I created a project from scratch. Back then in XCode 4 / 5 the developer was given the choice between storyboard or Xib to get the project started.  In Xcode 6 though every template is forced to get started as StoryBoard.

I have removed the story board. Then I have opened `info.plist` in Supporting files and set `Main storyboard file base name : Main` to `Main storyboard file base name: <blank>`.

Then I created a basic testViewController with Xib (same name).

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    testViewController *firstViewController = [[testViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:firstViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And this still shows me a black view controller. I checked the xib file, the File owner is set to the view controller and the view delegate is also set.
What am I missing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change these two things:

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

 testViewController *firstViewController = [[testViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

To this, and add this code, with the real name or you xib file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;  // Are you using ARC?

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// I think your xib files is testViewcontroller.xib, if not change it.
testViewController *firstViewController = [[testViewController alloc] initWithNibName:testViewController.xib bundle:nil];
// change this also
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```